# Extracting .js files from a website / file using beautifullsoup and python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to obtain javascript ".js" files from a website using beautifulsoup. This is the code I'm using at the moment which works but misses on some files

```
jss = soup.findAll(name = 'script', attrs = { 'src': re.compile('\.js') })
```

for example js file:

```
src=http://krebsonsecurity.com/wp-content/plugins/comment-rating-pro/ck-karma.js?ver=3.3.2
```

then it misses.

Anyone knows of the best implementation to be able to extract js files.

Cheers

Comment: Have you experimented with using different regular expressions?

Comment: I tried with a few examples I found online but they didn't work, either including links which were not .js files or missing on a few.

Comment: Hmmm. I tested out the above js link and "\.js" works fine for me. Are you sure that was the problem?

Comment: apparently, it didn't work for me, it did but missed a few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the limit on what the value of the `src` is (beyond "having a src").:

```
re.compile('\.+')
```

Comment: This actually solved it. Cheers Mate....but it might also include any other scripts, can't think of any :p maybe I should put a check to see if the src value includes .js files like link.find(".js")==1

Comment: some websites, suppose amazon have included .js files within scripts ex: " <script type='text/javascript'>"
Im currently using the following re expression to find URLs that start with http:// and www.
is there anyway to combine re.compile('\.+') and re.findall(r'http[s]?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+' to find .js files? Sorry i have no idea how re expressions work and its beyond my intelligence!

Comment: If you want to get inline scripts as well, then get rid of the `attrs` bit entirely. Once you have the script elements loop over them to see if they have a src attribute. If they do, download the resource at the URL. If they don't, get the content.